# Set New Page Default Settings to "Inherit default page layout from parent site" in sharepoint 2013 using powershell script

Tags: 2013, powershell, sharepoint-server, page-layout

I want to set New Page Default Settings to "Inherit default page layout from parent site" in sharepoint 2013 subsites using powershell script. I have tried with publishing-web IsInheritingDefaultPageLayout property but it is read-only property.This can be done manually via SharePoint GUI (Site Settings / Look and Feel / Page Layouts and site templates) but i want to do this settings using powershell script.Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Done with below code.

Use `InheritDefaultPageLayout` method instead of `IsInheritingDefaultPageLayout` property.

```
$pweb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($subsite)
$pweb.InheritDefaultPageLayout();
$pWeb.Update();
```